# Visual Studio adding class library - prefix with Solution name

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

This is going to probably going to sound really silly but I am not sure what happened. 
My hard drive crashed and I had to re-install software including Visual Studio 2012.

OK. Installed. Create solution. Add a class library.

Created solution 'MySolution'

Add new Class library 'Common'

**Previously:**
The code behind namespace: ***MySolution.Common***

**Now:**
The code behind namespace: ***Common***

I don't recall doing any specific settings but I would really want the namespace to be MySolution.Common again.

Any advice on how I would set the namespace is greatly appreciated. 
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to set the "default namespace" of your library project (`Project properties > Application tab`).

Comment: Thanks Ken. I just don't recall ever needing to do that. Well...lesson learned for next time. Thanks again!